# jquerymobileでボタンクリック時の動作について

Tags: monaca, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

jquerymobileでダイアログをポップアップし、フォームの入力画面がでて入力したら
データが保存され、元の画面に切り替わるということをしたいです。

今の状態ですと、ポップアップのボタンをクリックさせても画面が切り替わらないので切り替わるようにしたいです。

```js
(function() {
  $("#time1").click(ontime1);
});

function ontime1() {
 var te1 = $("#t1").val();
 var tt1 = {
  t1:te1, 
 }
 localStorage.setItem("time1", JSON.stringify(tt1));
 $.mobile.changePage("#tk11", { reverse: true });
}
```

```html
<div data-role="page">
 <div id="popup" data-role="popup" data-overlay-theme="b"
   data-dismissible="false" style="max-width:500px;">
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
   <h1>てすと</h1>
  </div>
  <div role="main" class="ui-content">
   <form>
    <fieldset>
     <p>日付をいれる。</p>
     <label for="jquery-ui-dialog-form-name">日付</label>
     <input type="date" name="jquery-ui-dialog-form-name" id="t1" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" value="" />
     <a href="" id="time1" data-role="button" data-inline="false">設定</a>
     </p>
    </fieldset>
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div data-role="header" id="tk11">
  <h1>jQuery Mobile TIPS</h1>
 </div>
 <div role="main" class="ui-content">
  <table id="jquery-ui-dialog-table" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
   <thead>
    <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
     <th id="table-th-name">てす</th>
     <th id="table-th-comment">てす</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>てす</td>
     <td>てす</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="jquery-ui-button">
   <a href="#popup" data-rel="popup" data-transition="pop"
      class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-check">追加</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div data-role="footer">
  <h3>Copyright </h3>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

タッチデバイスだと `click` イベントが発生しないため、 [`tap` イベント](https://api.jquerymobile.com/tap/)をお使いになられると良いと思います。